# Magento 2.2.3 Cron job won't run. Status is missed. One is stuck in running. How to fix?

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

I am having an issue with my `Magento 2.2.3` using `PHP 7.1` My cron jobs are set as follows:

```
9,24,38,52 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/website/public_html/update/cron.php >> /home/stebbins/public_html/var/log/update.cron.log

1,25,39,55 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/website/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/stebbins/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log

0,9,39,49 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/website/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/stebbins/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

When I run the group crons via CLI it says they ran as scheduled, but nearly all appear as status "Missed" and "Too late for schedule". There are also 6 instances of the order export job with status of "running". Please see the screen shots below this message for the cPanel cron settings, `cron_schedule` table, and Magento admin cron settings.

I think this is due to the crons being "stuck", for lack of a better term and I've been reading the documentation at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html . I am having a really hard time getting this fixed and I'm spinning my wheels, so, I'm posting here to hopefully get an answer.

- Should I manually delete all the "running" jobs from the cron_schedule table?
- Is there a CLI command for Linux for this?
- Am I just barking up the wrong tree and do you have a better fix?

Thanks so much in advance!

---Screen shots below---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Should I manually delete all the "running" jobs from the cron_schedule
>   table?

Yes, execute query "delete from cron_scheduled where status = 'running'"

> Is there a CLI command for linux for this?

mysql ... -e "delete from cron_scheduled where status = 'running'"
:)

> Am I just barking up
>   the wrong tree and do you have a better fix?

Upgrade to Magento  2.2.6

Also, why you do not run cron every minute?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I manually deleted them from the table, flushed the cache, reindexed, and now all of them are running with success except orderexport. There are still a couple "missed" but then they run successfully.

Any idea why the orderexport would fail?

Also, I can't run every minute on this hosting. Its a shared server. 

Lastly, once I get this thing stable I'll take it to 2.2.6, actually, 2.3 but a failed upgrade is behind all of this actually.